# How to Search and Filter result in RecyclerView using Kotlin?

Tags: android, filter, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I want to add a search tool in my app without using The toolbar so i tried those codes but it is not giving me the required result.My real problem is that i did not know how to filter result from my ArrayList i used an EdiText with for loops but it does not work correctly Please Help me.

> List_of_Books

```
@Suppress("RECEIVER_NULLABILITY_MISMATCH_BASED_ON_JAVA_ANNOTATIONS")
class List_of_Books : AppCompatActivity() {

    var booksList:MutableList<Book> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_of__books)

        books_listView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this,2)
        booksList.add(Book("He Died with...", "Categorie Book", "Description book", R.drawable.hediedwith))
        booksList.add(Book("The Vegitarian", "Categorie Book", "Description book", R.drawable.thevigitarian))
    val myrv = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.books_listView)
    /* val myAdapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(this, lstBook)*/
    val myAdapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(this, booksList)

    myrv.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 3)
    /*  myrv.adapter = myAdapter*/
    myrv.adapter =myAdapter
```

> Book.kt

```
class Book(title: String, category: String, description: String, var thumbnail: Int) {

    var title: String? = title
    var category: String? = category
    var description: String? = description

}
```

> RecyclkerViewAdapter.kt

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter(private val mContext: List_of_Books, private val mData: List<Book>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mData.size
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {

        val view: View
        val mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cardveiw_item_book, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.tv_book_title.text = mData[position].title
        holder.img_book_thumbnail.setImageResource(mData[position].thumbnail)
        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(mContext, Book_Activity::class.java)

            // passing data to the book activity
            intent.putExtra("Title", mData[position].title)
            intent.putExtra("Description", mData[position].description)
            intent.putExtra("Thumbnail", mData[position].thumbnail)
            intent.putExtra("Category", mData[position].category)
            intent.putExtra("targetURL", "https://s1-physique.blogspot.com/")


            // start the activity
            mContext.startActivity(intent)
        }


    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        internal var tv_book_title: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_title_id) as TextView
        internal var img_book_thumbnail: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_img_id) as ImageView
        internal var cardView: CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_id) as CardView

    }


}
```

If you need Anything more please just tell me in comments.

Comment: I don't see any EditText or for-loops, can you show a more detail code?

Comment: Yes i have deleted because it does not give me a result,please if you have any idea just tell me how to filter this RecyclerView? and thanks ^_^

Comment: What do you want to filter? You can filter the list before pass it into the adapter.

Comment: i want to filter it a cording to the user search word

Comment: @pskink please explain  more how to do it ?

Comment: so do you know how to perform the filtering process?

Comment: nope i'm beginer